# automaticaly impossible to click element in Webdriver (python)

Tags: python, webdriver, chromium

I am trying to program a Python script which downloads table automatically from the webpage. The table is not fully loaded, when I simply go to the specified url address. I have to click link "Load more". This I tried to do by the script bellow.

```
delay = 2
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get("url")
time.sleep(delay + np.random.rand() )
click_except = 0
while click_except == 0:
try:
    driver.find_element_by_id("id").click()
        time.sleep(delay + np.random.rand() )
    except:
        click_except = 1
time.sleep(delay + np.random.rand() )
web = driver.find_element_by_id("id_table")
str = (web.text)
```

It worked before, but now it does not work... the same code! I moved to a different country and I am using different wi-fi. Can this have any effect? Actually the line with click command still works, when processed separately and manually. It does not work together with the While and Try cycle. Any idea what is wrong? Or any idea, how to programme it better?

The delay should give the webpage enough time to upload.

Comment: Including `numpy` to generate just an `int` seems overkill. Make sure you fix the script indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to avoid waiting for a time period, it is better to wait for specific element and selenium supports it, check: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

You can do something like:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get('url')
wait_for_id('id').click()
str = wait_for_id('id_table').text

def wait_for_id(identifier):
    """
    It waits for web element with identifier
    :return: found selenium web element
    """
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, identifier))
    )
    return element
```